# Copy relevant information from one postgreSQL database into separate schema in another postgreSQL database

Tags: database, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to copy the information from one database A into a separate schema in another database B. Database A is running on another server and I once I copy the data into B, I also want to keep the copy of A updated whenever A is updated in its server. I am using SQLAlchemy for querying in Python.
So, the process is:
1) Schema transfer
2) Data Transfer from A to B
3) keep A updated in B.

How do I achieve the above process?

Comment: If you are using Postgres 10 you could use logical replication to synchronize those two tables. If the connection between the servers is fast, you could also think about not replicating at all and using a foreign table to access the table in database A directly from database B

Comment: Thank you! I also thought to directly connect these 2 databases. But both of these databases are running on different servers. I might need to create a docker image with import functionality of database A to be used in database B. And also while accessing the database later it will require 2 queries, first for database A and 2nd for database B as I need to use data from first and then use it with data from the 2nd database. What should be the better method? And how exactly should I perform the replication part?

Comment: And could you please explain me a bit more about the pros and cons of both methods?

Comment: No, with a foreign table you do not require two queries. The "remote" table looks like an and can be used just like a  local table. You just distribute the load between the two servers

Comment: Maybe worth taking a look at `postgres_fdw`?
 https://robots.thoughtbot.com/postgres-foreign-data-wrapper - unless you're not going to perform joins using several foreign tables, it's a nice alternative. Otherwise take a look at `dblink`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html

Comment: @JimJones Thank you for your reply. I researched about `dblink`, but found out that if we need to JOIN different tables from foreign database then the process results are really bad. And it will also require multiple queries. But I am looking for a method which copies 
 the entire database from A into B so that I can fetch data with only 1 (single) query.

Comment: So I believe `postgres_fdw` is really the choice for you. Unless you can execute this query of yours in the foreign database to create a view, so that you don't need to execute these joins. Good luck!